# If a set $S$ has a choice function, does $\bigcup S$ have one too?

Tags: functions, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I have an exercise in a book that asserts that ***if a set $S$ has a choice function on it, then so does the union of all its elements $\bigcup S$*** (without assuming the axiom of choice). I, however, have serious doubts that this statement holds and I even have an argument against it. However, since I am up against the word of a textbook, I cannot be sure. I may just be missing something obvious. Hence, I want to verify my hunch.

First a little clarification of my terminology:

- By a choice function $C$ on a set $S$, I mean a function $C : \wp(S)\setminus\{\emptyset\} \to S$ such that $C(\sigma) \in \sigma$.
- For a set $S$, $\bigcup S = \{x \in \mathcal{U} : \exists y \in S\text{ s.t. } x \in y\}$ ($\mathcal{U}$ is the universal class) i.e. it is union of all the elements of $S$.

Now, my argument against the book's assertion is this: if the axiom of choice (AOC) were false, then there would be a set $\Sigma$ which has no choice functions on it. Consider, now, the singleton set $\{\Sigma\}$; it clearly has a choice function on it but its union doesn't as $\bigcup \{\Sigma\} = \Sigma$. Hence, if AOC were false, then I can prove this statement false using the other axioms of set theory. Thus, contrapositively, if I could prove this exercise true using just the other axioms of set theory, I could prove AOC too which seems ridiculous! Is my reasoning correct? Or am I mistaken somewhere?

Comment: What book is this from?

Comment: [Smullyan and Fitting's Set Theory and the Continuum Problem](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486474844.html).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I will cross out that exercise in the book. For everyone's reference, it is exercise 4.3 of Chapter 4.

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Of course not. Your proof is perfectly valid.

This is also mentioned in the [errata](https://id144254.securedata.net/melvinfitting/errata/book_errors/RevisedSetBookErrors/split.html) for the book.